# JUnit Black Box Versus White Box Testing

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to understand what black box and white box testing means when it comes to JUnit testing. Would the following code be an example of white box testing?

UserTest.java:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals("John", User.name);
}
```

User.java:

```
public class User {
    private final String name = "John";
}
```

If someone can provide me a specific example of white box vs black box testing using JUnit, that would be great because I don't see the difference clearly.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@adrianbooth/test-driven-development-wars-detroit-vs-london-classicist-vs-mockist-9956c78ae95f) You'll have some example of white/black box approches. And to answer to your question, your example is too trivial to be either black box or white box, it's not even a test. Basically, black box only verifies the output and white box will also make assertions against the internal behaviour and components

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think your example will work if `name` is `private`.

Secondly, this is way too opinion-based. The canonical definition is that black-box testing is when your test is ignorant of the underlying functionality of the thing under test. So you could argue that all testing is black-box, just at different scopes.

It seems like your example test is accessing private state, which feels white-box-ish. Most users of your application would never care about the values of private state.